# ReadableStream when I echo data to Vue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, codeigniter

I am trying to call a CI3 function using the fetch method in Vue (JS).
My fetch code looks like this:

```
fetch("https://YOUR_LINK", requestOptions)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.body;
                    })
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

My CI3 controller functions looks like:

```
 $ret = new stdClass();

        $ret->total_count           = 0;
        $ret->incomplete_results    = false;
        $ret->items                 = array();

        $jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
        $termen = $jsonArray['q'];

        $url = 'PRIVATE_LINKq='.$termen;

        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = "http://PRIVATE_LINK_HERE?q=" . $termen . "&format=json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $headers = [
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'
        ];

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $res = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);


        $adrese = json_decode($res);


        foreach($adrese as $a) {
            $ret->total_count+= 1;
            $item = new stdClass();
      
            $item->Id = $a->place_id;
            $item->Nume =  $a->display_name;
            $item->Long = $a->lat;
            $item->Lat = $a->lon;
            $ret->items[] = $item;
        }

       echo json_encode($ret);
```

The problem is that I can't get the content of ret in my frontend. I've tried everything but each time I get

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
```

How can I get the response as an object in frontend?

Thanks in advance and Happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to get a JSON from the endpoint, you need to get the body as json, try this:

```
fetch("https://YOUR_LINK", requestOptions)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: My endpoint returns a json format already. If I return `response.json()` I get an `Unknown token error`

Comment: I added `response.json()` and now I can see the response in the network tab of the console, but I get the `unkown token at position` error. The code is exactly as the one suggested by you.

Comment: Not sure if there is anything wrong with the JSON, try `response.text()` instead `response.json()`

Comment: it works with text, do I need to encode it again for processing ?

Comment: You need to respond the endpoint with a `application/json` Content-Type header

Comment: Please modify your answer with the comment you've made `response.text()` so I can accept it

Comment: @SpeedoCoder changed